Error while using foreach for PySpark dataframe
I have a PySpark dataframe base_df.
And want to store each row of it as json in AWS S3 bucket.
Have implemented following function for that -
def write_final_json(self, row)->None:
        print("write_final_json")
        print(row)
        output_dir = self.args['DESTINATION_S3_PATH']
        """
        Args:
        output_dir: S3 path or linux dir based on env
        row: record from datafrome

        Purpose: Write final json output to S3
        """
        if not os.path.exists(f"{output_dir}/{row.batch_id}"):
            os.makedirs(f"{output_dir}/{row.batch_id}")
        print(f"Writing {output_dir}/{row.batch_id}/{row.member_id}.json")
        with open(f"{output_dir}/{row.batch_id}/{row.member_id}.json", "w") as f:
            f.write(row)

And to apply the above method for each row I am doing like this -
base_df.foreach(lambda row: self.write_final_json(row))

But getting below error -
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Can someone please help me to identify why I am facing this issue.
Thanks !!

Try to move the function to be standalone and not part of the class that the SparkSession is initialized.

If you are iterating over rows, it is likely that your dataset is small, and you may not need Spark. In such cases, it would be more efficient to collect the data on the driver and write it using your preferred tool.

you don't have to write each row by yourself in Spark, instead you can use partitionBy and write functions
base_df.write \
    .partitionBy('batch_id', 'member_id') \ # Saving into output_dir/batch_id=${batch_id}/member_id=${member_id}/...
    .mode('append') \ # Append to this directory, or 'overwrite' if you want
    .format('json') \ # Format to json automatically 
    .save(output_dir)


Thanks @Islam for your answer it does creates the json file for each row. But it creates a member_id folder inside batch_id folder. I want the json files to be direclty under batch_id folder. It will be very helpful if you can please let me know how it can be achieved.

Ahh, AFAIK it is not possible to output a file per column value in spark, but instead it will output a directory with sub files, I'm not sure if it'd be acceptable this way for you, but it is a good practice to have a directory and you append a new file with each update
